# Pronoun trolling - what to do?

Tags: discussion, support

Consider [this post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/221861/16835) (edit: now deleted as abusive by the 'community' automated user.) Since it's been edited, here's its original version:

> Me and my four friends are big MCU fans and we are thinking of
> starting to read the comic books to understand the lore a bit better.
>
> I'm wondering if any characters have my pronouns or my friends
> pronouns, Adam (pronouns he/him) says Marvel is very LGBTQIAA+
> friendly but when my friend Quince (pronouns zir/zhey) asked if any
> characters have neopronouns Adam said he doesn't think so which upset
> zhey.
>
> My two other friends Baster (pronouns fret/from) and Piel (pronouns
> var/let) said that there are tonnes of characters in the MCU so surely
> one of must do. Var googled for any information but couldn't find any
> and fret though about signing up to a comic forum to ask but they
> don't have such a friendly code of conduct for new users so I've asked
> here.
>
> So to sum up I'm asking for MCU (or any comic character) with the
> following neo pronouns:
>
> - Zir/zhey
> - Fret/from
> - Var/let
> - Grimble/gromble (these are my pronouns)
>
> Thanks, baster is desperate to have a superhero with the same pronouns
> as from (My pronouns are grimble/gromble)

This is a pronoun trolling post. I know it, you know it. grimble-grombles know it :-)

Anyway, should it just be closed (note: It had already been closed and reopened), or - edited into something useful, e.g.:

> Are there comic book characters in the Marvel Comic Universe (or possibly other settings) which have any characters with non-traditional personal pronouns / neo-pronouns (such as [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third-person_pronoun#Historical_and_dialectal_gender-neutral_pronouns))?

Comment: It was already closed but has subsequently been reopened. It is highly likely to be a troll post aye, especially given the timing and follow up comments even if the post itself wasn't obvious enough.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: Edited this bit of information in, thank you. My question stands though.

Comment: I'd vote to close it myself but having already been successful in doing so I can't again. However, it's at -9 so won't show up on the homepage anymore so even if it doesn't get closed I'm happy to let it die in the depths where it won't be seen.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: So, you don't believe the "salvage" would have been worth it? I mean, the two-liner I suggested would have been a valid question.

Comment: My personal opinion is "don't feed the trolls" i.e. leave it as is and let it die. However, I'm aware others would like to salvage it and turn it into something reasonable so it can stay open. It's really up to you if you think it's worth it.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: I couldn't decide, which is why I asked. But ok.

Comment: It's also worth noting that question was linked on main meta so it has extra eyes on it, not all doing what is best.

Comment: Editing it into shape means that you're going to give a troll account a boost.

Comment: @Valorum: That's a good point. Didn't think of that.

Comment: Yeah that seems pretty suspicious to me.  All the pronoun choices seem extremely non-standard, like confusingly so.  Looking up the words + pronoun seems to give the question as top results.  That doesn't _prove_ anything; but it definitely raises my suspicion, even more so than just "grimble/gromble" on their own.

Comment: It seems impolite to call the OP a troll just because grimble got his pronouns from what is presumably gromble's [favorite band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gnome).

Comment: We need to start dragging up a lot of older posts and delete them as well then. There have many questions that are borderline trolls but they stayed open maybe with an edit and received answers all the same.

Comment: @Valorum "Vote for the post, not the user" though :p

Comment: FWIW, "Grimble/Gromble" [has previously been used elsewhere on the network](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/146517/members-of-the-company-using-team-bathroom) and declared trollish.

Comment: @MishaR: If it weren't, I wouldn't ask this question. That was the dilemma - whether or not to salvage a decent question out of the grimble-grombleness.

Comment: @Einpoklum Whoops, sorry, deleted comment before seeing reply, was worried it may be seen as trolling too. Actually, I wonder if the phrasing may have been more of an (unsuccessful) attempt at light humor than actual abusive trolling. Different people have different relationships with gender dynamics, and it isn't an equally important issue for everyone. And we do often assign the worst possible motives given relatively little information.

Comment: @MishaR: The "friends" story was pretty outlandish. Also, I distinguish between gender dynamics and the use of, well, outlandish pronouns. You would be hard-pressed to describe the gender identity which corresponds to grimble/gromble or the other stuff.

Comment: @Einpoklum Oh, it was certainly done for comedy's sake - no doubt about that. I am just not sure that there is enough information here to say that it was intended to be abusive. As for it being trolling, I would say that trolling - even if not abusive - *does* warrant closure, but that only holds when there is no good underlying question.

Comment: @einpoklum-reinstateMonica "whether or not to salvage a decent question out of the grimble-grombleness." I nominate that for "quote of the day", Your Grombleness.

Comment: The phrase "nuke from orbit" comes to mind for that "question".

Comment: I am not native English speaker. The post did not look to me like it was made for trolling purposes until I came across that last bullet point "Grimble/gromble (these are my pronouns)". So, which pronouns from above, aside from grimble/gromble, are also fake?

Comment: @wha7ever: At least the last 3 of the 4 pairs. About the first pair I'm not sure. But the tone of the post is also bemused in a way that a trolling post might be.

Comment: Personally I don't much care what pronouns people use when referring to me but I have definite preferences when it comes to nouns and adjectives.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've come around to @Valorum's position, which is:

> Editing it into shape means that you're going to give a troll account a boost.

So even if it could be salvaged by a deep-cutting edit, it's not a good idea to do this. So a Close vote, possibly flagging, and a down-vote with an explanation (like the one I made on the grumble-gromble question).

Now, it's true that the explanation violates the suggestion of "Don't feed the trolls" - but for fairness, and the off chance I could be convinced it wasn't trolling after all, I'd still justify the downvote.

Answer (score 32):

The problem with questions like this is that it's basically a live hand grenade waiting for some imbecile to throw themselves upon it.

While it seems reasonably clear and common sense that grimble and gromble are not appropriate personal pronouns and that this person is a troll, anyone who dares to say such a thing is likely to be flagged and/or openly accused of being a transphobe.

> "*I'm thinking the mods have closed it because I'm trans and they may be transphobic. Thanks again*"

### Normal users should not be having to deal with this question. It was flagged for moderator attention days ago and while some of our mods are on strike, others aren't.

### **AncientSwordRage and/or Thaddeus should be doing something about this. It's baffling that they're just letting it lie.**

Comment: Note that my salvage does not actually deny that the poster or his/her/their/xir/grumble/gromble (huh! dodged that one!) friends actually use those pronouns, it just sort of moves away from the hand-grenade, hopefully.

Comment: @einpoklum - when you edit this question into shape it'll undoubtedly pick up upvotes. That can't be a good thing if you think this might be a troll

Comment: I agree with this except that this is not the responsibility of the elected mods, either. SE created this mess and is still iterating their official FAQs on the new CoC. Elected mods don't have clear guidance on what to actually do with this post, therefore in the meantime SE needs to clean it up. I don't know if ASR and Thaddeus have seen the post but I do know that several CMs have seen it and *they* are just letting it lie.

Comment: @Null - Which is frankly gutless

Comment: @Valorum I'm not often able to look at flag *en masse*, so I have been ***very*** late to the party. Some of these should now be sorted.

Comment: While I admire you calling out our inactive moderators, we have always "fed trolls" on this site, at least to the extent where a question can be revised to something legitimate, which the example here could have been.

Comment: @Skooba - If you like a troll question, re-ask it.

Answer (score 25):

A new FAQ regarding the updated CoC is due out shortly. I've seen a draft of it but until it is public it is not official, and until official guidance is due out I don't think it makes any sense for any elected moderators -- whether on strike or not -- to handle such issues. After all, SE has already summarily removed a respected moderator before the CoC was updated (and certainly before any FAQs were written) with the [dubious claim that she violated the CoC at the time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334271/299342); elected moderators do not have the proper guidance on how to handle such a post, which is largely [why I have suspended by activity as a moderator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334091/299342) for the time being. **Handling this post should be the responsibility of an actual employee of SE (i.e. a CM)**, at the very least until the official FAQ is finalized (and I know several CMs have seen the post).

As for normal users, judge for yourself whether or not the post is on-topic and vote accordingly (or just leave it alone).

Comment: I don't care about the CoC. It's a hostile SE Inc. artifact. I was asking my fellow community members what to do in this situation.

Comment: @einpoklum Whether you care for it or not doesn't matter. As a user of the network you are bound by it and it is the new CoC, specifically the FAQ that caused this situation in the first place so it is relevant here.

Comment: @einpoklum You may not care about the CoC but SE cares that you follow the CoC. SE has not explained how to distinguish between trolling and a legitimate request to use neopronouns so I would advise against closing a question solely on the basis that you think it is trolling. Also, the last (public) guidance I saw regarding the CoC is that you should not edit out information about a user's preferred pronouns in the post. That looks like it might be changing based on the proposed new FAQ due out tomorrow but until things are finalized I'd be careful what you edit.

Comment: @Null: Yeah, I don't know about all that. I'll do what I believe is appropriate and if Fullerton/Chipps/etc. don't like it they or moderators loyal to them can throw me out. Actually that can happen even if I _do_ follow the CoC, like in the case of Monica Ciello, so like I said - I don't let that worry me.

Comment: @Null - So we're back to "it's a live hand grenade" then?

Comment: @Valorum Of course it's a live hand grenade. A respected moderator was summarily removed for pre-thoughtcrime over this issue. I, personally, will not touch any post like this until at the very least the official FAQ is finalized. I advise any other user to do the same. SE created this mess so let them clean it up.

Comment: @Null: Could you clarify your post with your latest comment?

Comment: @einpoklum - Indeed. This seems highly relevant info, especially if it represents the general thinking of our moderator team

Comment: @einpoklum I don't know what my latest comment would add to my post. I said in my post that it's the responsibility of the CMs (i.e. SE) to deal with it. [I've called out SE on their claim that Monica violated the CoC at the time she was removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334271/299342), which means that she was removed for pre-thoughtcrime. And since at least one moderator has been removed based on rules that didn't even exist at the time, I advise any user to also avoid doing anything which might conflict with rules that are not yet public and official.

Comment: @Valorum I speak for only myself here.

Comment: @Null: It would allow me to un-downvote it, which I would do given the comment.

Comment: @einpoklum I'm not worried about the downvote but I've clarified why I don't think the elected moderators should be dealing with this (which is my only disagreement with Valorum's answer).

Comment: @Null - In which case the elected mods should put a comment on to explain their unwillingness to deal with the flags.

Comment: @Valorum - you must never have played hot-potato, especially not with live hand grenades. "just letting it lie" is what we should all be doing. That's what they're doing; want us to do, and what I will do because I'm already tired of this. Apology failed and they're not going to recant; no other choice for either us.

Comment: @Null "pre-thoughtcrime" should be Merriam Webster's word of the year. It will come increasingly in handy.

Answer (score 20):

## The new Code of Conduct doesn't give you room to do anything about it.

Neo-pronouns are not clearly defined, there is no authoritative list of them, they're rarely used, and they don't follow common English grammatical principles.

Any other set of words that would fit that criteria would be edited or corrected to fit modern English convention, but the new CoC states that neo-pronouns are the exception to this because they are "part of a user's identity."

Comment: While neopronouns are not clearly defined. Identifying yourself as grimble gromble the gnome certainly suggests that you're not taking the whole thing seriously.

Comment: @Valorum In what way does it suggest that?

Comment: Because Grmble gromble was the funny gnome from a pink Floyd song

Comment: @Valorum But how does that invalidate it? I'm not trying to be a smartass. I guess the point I'm trying to make is that the very nature of neopronouns is that when you drill down deep enough you see that they *don't* play by any established rules of English. One requests them, which thus makes them valid.

Comment: "This is a pronoun trolling post. I know it, you know it. grimble-grombles know it." - I honestly didn't. And even if I did there's nothing I can (nor would) do about it. +1

Comment: As a not native English speaker it is very difficult for me to differentiate troll pronouns from non-troll pronouns. (I am guessing native English speaker have similar troubles, too). I also don't listen to Pink Floyd and can't know names of all the gnomes Pink Floyd is singing about. +1

Answer (score 6):

Since we're roughly 4 years removed from the Monica debacle that was raging during the original post, I thought I would make explicit why this was trolling and not a serious post. There were some folks arguing this was a good faith question and those who did not agree couldn't articulate why it wasn't. The big tell is in their list of pronouns

> Zir/zhey

As with any good troll, they don't want to give away the farm just yet. Zir and zhey(more commonly spelled zey) are probably the best-known non-standard pronouns.

> Fret/from

The problem here is that these are regular words. While there are some exotic pronouns, if you want people to actually use them you try to make them familiar but distinct (i.e. [the most used ones look relatively similar to the familiar "he"/"her" pronouns](https://intercultural.uncg.edu/wp-content/uploads/Neopronouns-Explained-UNCG-Intercultural-Engagement.pdf)). These would be incredibly hard to use as pronouns in any normal context

> Var/let

There's the troll. These words make even less sense than the previous set. These aren't pronouns at all. How do I know? The relationship between the two words. The only place where these two words are used together in any meaningful context is [the programming language JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/762011/2370483). In other words, these are keywords for variable declarations, not neo-pronouns.

> Grimble/gromble (these are my pronouns)

This almost certainly a reference to a [Pink Floyd song called "The Gnome"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gnome), which is told from the perspective of a gnome named Grimble Grumble. The second word was spelled slightly differently so it would be slightly less recognizable.

Comment: Perhaps the OP is telling us they are a varlet.

Answer (score 0):

Before I saw this question, I edited the question to something reasonable that is at least on-topic. I preserved the OP's pronouns, but removed the tangential chatter that isn't really part of the question and that seems to have generated the most controversy. It isn't that we don't want to hear about the asker's friends and pronouns, but that they aren't relevant to grimble's actual question. The same would be done for any question on any Stack Exchange site - while it may be interesting that a user encountered a particular error message from their C compiler while programming from a cafe in Miami, geography isn't likely part of the underlying issue.

Let's assume that the question was asked in good faith and try to move on, maybe even getting a good answer.

Comment: Editing the question into shape, reopening it and even answering it is just letting the troll win and giving them a boost. We don't want that. We've already spent way too much time on this and giving the troll what they want. Just let the post die.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot we don't delete posts because we aren't happy with the poster's behavior or character. We delete them because they are off-topic or very low quality.

Comment: @RobertColumbia I don't know where you've gotten "delete" from as I never said that. We also don't feed trolls and have never done that. I'd be happy to let the question be open and might even upvote it if it was asked in good faith but this wasn't. We shouldn't let bad faith posts and trolls on the site period.

Comment: What does keeping the sentence 'My pronouns are grimble/gromble.' adds to the question? "Are there Marvel characters that uses neo-pronouns?" is a valid question, everything else is fluff that detracts from the question.

Answer (score -3):

I voted to reopen the question because it's not all that crazy a question.

Marvel has recently had a huge push for inclusivity, and multiple people in Marvel have explicitly stated that they want more members from the LGBTQ+ crowd represented:

> Marvel Studios EVP of Production Victoria Alonso says the Disney-owned studio is “actively” working towards a more diverse and inclusive Marvel Cinematic Universe.
>
> “I would feel honored to have a member of the LGBTQ+ group represented in our films and I hope the future shows that,” Alonso wrote in a Reddit Q&A Wednesday when asked about the addition of LGBTQ+ characters to the ever-expanding franchise.
>
> ...
>
> Marvel’s Runaways highlights a lesbian romance between Nico (Lyric Okano) and Karolina (Virginia Gardner), but scenes touching on Valkyrie’s (Tessa Thompson) and Okoye’s (Danai Gurira) bisexuality were deleted from Thor: Ragnarok and Black Panther, respectively.
>
> The franchise will also feature its first trans actors in Spider-Man: Far From Home, in theaters July 2, and Russo in May promised the MCU will receive its first LGBTQ+ superhero “very soon.”
>
> [Marvel Studios Promises More Diversity and Inclusivity in Phase 4 and Beyond](https://comicbook.com/marvel/2019/06/05/marvel-studios-more-diversity-inclusivity-lgbtq-phase-4-beyond-victoria-alonso/)

Though I don't know the current run of Marvel to answer it myself, I wouldn't be surprised at all to hear there was a minor hero or villain with non-conventional preferred pronouns. And I really don't want this site to set the precedence that non-conventional pronoun usage is trolling.

Comment: _"And I really don't want this site to set the precedence that non-conventional pronoun usage is trolling."_ - non conventional pronoun use isn't trolling but this question is.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot So what's trolling about it, if not the non-conventional pronouns? I would really like to understand that.

Comment: The way it's worded, the OP's pronouns, the comments by the OP on the post.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I don't follow, you just said non-conventional pronoun use isn't trolling, but at the same time the OP's pronouns indicate trolling. The comments look fine, too. I flagged the accusation that the mods may be transphobic, but other than that several comments seem pretty in favor of re-opening it.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Again, I'm good on the general concept of flagging if there's trolling, but I'm not convinced this is trolling. It's a solid question about sci-fi, even limiting itself to a specific company.

Comment: If you can't see what's trolling about the question I really can't help you see it. And there's a difference between non-conventional pronouns and trolling pronouns but considering the state SE is in at the moment I don't really want to go too far down that route. That's just one factor that led me to believe it's a troll.

Comment: The comments by the OP... not the comments in general. More specifically how they seem very aware of how the site works considering it's a brand new account and the second comment, that you flagged, in particular.

Comment: @GGMG-he-him It's definitely very strange that they spent so much of the original post dedicated to explaining their own pronouns, and their friends pronouns.  What's especially strange to me is that a majority of the pronouns they use are so non-standard that you can google them + "pronoun" and the first hit is that SE question.  When combined with everything going on in SE... it definitely raises a lot of flags.

Comment: @JMac Exactly, forgot to add "the timing" into it when I posted my above comment.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I need specifics. What do you have that makes you think that the user is "very aware of how the site works?" Mods didn't close the question, users did. If anything, this user explicitly doesn't know how the site works.

Comment: It's just an overall impression of everything combined together. Like I said if you don't see it, you don't see it. There's not much I can really do to point to exactly what makes it look like a troll post.

Comment: "don't want to set the precedent that non-conventional pronoun usage is trolling" - there's non-conventional, and then there's grimble-gromble. And bringing up OP's friends' supposed pronouns. You should not have reopened under these circumstances.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot This is incredibly disappointing. I really wish I could have come away with more to work with than "an overall impression", it leaves a bad taste in my mouth that I could ask the exact same question with a higher rep and more conventional pronouns and get a free pass.

Comment: If you asked the "exact same question" as in the exact same wording I'd still be confident it was a troll post. Please don't take the things I say out of context of the overall picture. As I said it's all the things combined not particular things in isolation.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I mean, "The OP's pronouns": I don't have them, I have he-him. "The comments by the OP on the post": Not sure how this would play out, if I got my post closed for mentioning that my pronouns are he/him in a post sparked by my friends talking about neo-pronouns I'd at least privately accuse the mods of misconduct. A question about Marvel heroes is absolutely on-topic. "The way it's worded": it's been edited into shape. Lethal, help me here. Quote something, give me an IP search, find other questions on the network, do something other than sell me on a feeling, or we disengage.

Comment: @GGMG-he-him _""The OP's pronouns": I don't have them, I have he-him"_ - right but I'm talking about the OP of the question not yourself. _""The way it's worded": it's been edited into shape."_ but I'm not talking about what it is now am I? I'm talking about what the OP wrote not what others have changed it to since.

Comment: For specifics see what some other users have written JMac and some of the comments on the question itself.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot "If you asked the 'exact same question' as in the exact same wording I'd still be confident it was a troll post."... "right but I'm talking about the OP of the question not yourself." Sorry, I'm done. This comment string isn't a good option for conversation, we're both clearly on two separate threads of thought here. Vote however you like.

Comment: @GGMG-he-him Yes I said the "exact same wording" and you changed it to _""The OP's pronouns": I don't have them, I have he-him."_ which wouldn't then be the same wording because you'd have changed bits. I'm fine with not continuing this though as I doubt we'll agree on it.

Comment: @GGMG-he-him Paraphrased from [Supreme Court Justice Potter Stewart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_know_it_when_I_see_it) "I shall not today attempt further to define the kinds of material I understand to be embraced within that shorthand description [trolling], and perhaps I could never succeed in intelligibly doing so. *But I know it when I see it*."

Comment: Welcome to the Internet! Don't feed the trolls.

Comment: FWIW something I had forgotten but was reminded of recently, a similarly named doughnut "new" user posted a pronoun troll post on The Workplace with the same pronouns. It was even more clear that it was a troll post than this one.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Okay, that changes things. Wish you had remembered that sooner, do you have a link?

Comment: It was deleted relatively quickly if I remember correctly.